# Terminal: run program in background with identifier or specified name

Tags: php, background-process

How can I run a program or a script and identify it later to check if it's still running?

For example: I'm running a PHP script in background which runs about 10 hours (fetching a lot of data from different APIs etc.). When I run *top* I see the process *php* is still running. But what if I'm running a second PHP script at the same time? How can I identify which one is the first one, and which the second one?

I need that because I want to know if the script is still running after a few hours or not..

**UPDATE**

I'm using the following command to identify the PHP process and see if it's still running:

```
ps cax | grep "php$" | grep -o '^[ ]*[0-9]*'
```

I'm using that with PHP like `$pid = exec("..");` and then checking if `$pid` is greater than 0. If not, it's not running, else it is running and I have the process id.

Comment: How do you invoke the script? From web page or directly from shell or some other way?

Comment: I have a PHP file on my webserver, which runs another PHP script using `exec`.

Comment: If you run another script using exec, it usually shows the script name in top (assuming you executing a script with shebang).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: You can't.

The medium answer: Outside of the parent process that started your PHP process you can't identify the process with 100% reliability.

The long answer: [Bash Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#I_want_to_do_something_with_a_process_I_started_earlier)

What it boils down to is that `top`, `ps` and so on can not be relied upon to definitively identify processes started by another process. Processes die unexpectedly. PIDs are recycled. Process names can be altered.

Can you launch everything from a single, long-lived daemon/process? That's your best bet. At the very least have the parent process store the PID of the PHP process...though this is not foolproof. If you're willing to live with a risk of things going horribly wrong then read that page to find out ways you can mitigate the risks.

(Granted, the tone of that page is pretty rigid but the goal of that site is correctness. If you aren't running a mission critical service or something that people's lives depend on you can fudge things a bit.)

To answer the second part, if you have what you think is the correct PID then you can determine whether it is still running with

```
kill -0 <PID> && echo 'The process is still running!'
```

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: Read the web page that I linked. You can't reliably identify a process by name.

Comment: OK thanks! The solution to store the process ID in a separate file sounds interesting. But how do I know then if the process with this PID is still running?

Comment: I updated my answer with a reliable method.

Comment: But PIDs can be reused - what if the script has finished and some other process uses that PID? Then I also can't determine if it's still running or not ..

Comment: Exactly. Only if the parent process is still alive and monitoring the child process can you 100% reliably do all this. Otherwise...well...most of the time things will be fine. You have to decide if you can live with those rare times when they aren't fine. If you can't then keep the parent alive and monitor things through it.

Comment: The parent process is just a PHP file that is executed over a HTTP request. So the parent process isn't alive that long. But I think I can live with that!

Comment: Alternatively, rethink everything...why do you have two processes that so depend on what each is doing? Is there any other way to do things?

Answer (score 1):

Run your script directly by using [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) (`#!/usr/bin/php` in the first line and mark script as executable). `ps ax` will show the script name in the output, eg. `/usr/bin/php /path/to/your/script`.

Alternatively you could save the PID to another file from your calling script. To check if your script is running, check if a process with that PID exists (you probably should also check that `cmdline` or `exec` matches, since PIDs are reused).

As explained by [@B Layer's Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/388648/239817)as well, neither of these two are 100% reliable.

Comment: I think I'll try that one! But what if the Script is running on a Windows server? I hope I don't need to edit my script to run on a Windows server, but I think I should consider it ..

Comment: On Windows you need to execute php interpreter directly instead of relying on shebang, which is UNIX specific. You might be able to use file associations in Windows for same result.